# An analogy often given for sound is that of ~

Tags: pronouns

> An analogy often given for sound is that of throwing a small stone onto the surface of a still pond.

Does the 'that' mean an analogy?

Comment: _That_ means 'the one' or 'the analogy' (since _analogy_ has already been mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

The sentence means:

> analogy often associated with sound = throwing a small stone onto the surface of a still pond

So yes it refers to the analogy (often given for sound)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "that" refers to "analogy".

> An analogy often given for sound is **that** of throwing a small stone onto the surface of a still pond.

Means:

> An analogy often given for sound is **the analogy** of throwing a small stone onto the surface of a still pond.